# How to exit a wpf application when Application.Current is NULL?

Tags: wpf

When i need to exit a `WPF Application` i usually use `Application.Current.Shutdown()` but sometimes the  `Application.Current`is `NULL`,I also tried `Environment.Exit(0)` but it doesn't work correctly.
Is there any other way to exit a `WPF Application`specialy when `Application.Current` is `NULL`?

this is my code:

```
 public partial class App : Application
 {
    protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
      if (something)
        {
          continue....
        }
      else
        {
        Application.Current.Shutdown()
        }
  }
```

Comment: From what context you're calling Application.Current? could you post code you're using?

Comment: I want to close my entire application!and there is just one `System.Windows.Application` for any `AppDomain`.

Comment: Have you tried this.Close(); ??

Comment: @apomene:what do you mean by this?
 I use this code in `App.xaml` and the in no This here!!!

Comment: the first time I've heard that `Application.Current` could be null. At least right after the main window was loaded, there is no reason `Application.Current` could be null.

Comment: @KingKing:When you close a window(the only window that is open)and do something in the middle time before you open the next window ,the application would be shutdown so Application.Current would be null although it's still running.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().Kill();
```

Anywhere and anytime this terminates your application immediately.

Answer (score 0):

This is obviously per design. why would there be an application available when its startup didnt complete yet. Just do this.

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        if (false)
        {
            //
        }
        else
        {
            this.Shutdown();
        }
    }
}
```